# mssql query for checking whether the sum is even, odd or zero?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get:

- 0 if sum(apples) is 0
- 1 if sum(apples) is odd
- 2 if sum(apples) is
  even

how do i write such a query ?

```
    select answer = 
      case sum(apples)%2
         when 1 then 1
         else 2 
      end
    from fruits
```

I need a third option 0 if the sum is zero ...
My problem is that sum(apples)%2 returns 0 both in even and zero cases.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your query to the following way.

```
   select answer = 
      case 
          WHEN sum(apples)=0 then 0
          WHEN sum(apples)%2 = 1 then 1
         else 2 
      end
    from fruits
```

as per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) you have two option for syntax, you just needed to change to second option

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

or

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list
END CASE
```

Comment: sum(apples)%2 returns 0 whether it's 0 or even ... that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this little snippet of code in the way that you want...

```
declare @n int = 0
select case @n when 0 then 'zero' else (case (@n%2) when 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end) end
```

try it with other values for @n.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how `apples` column is defined (it's mandatory or it allows `NULL`s) `SUM` could return a non-NULL *value* or it could return NULL:

```
SELECT  x.OrderID,
        SUM(x.Qty) AS SumOfQty,
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(x.Qty) = 0 THEN 0
            WHEN SUM(x.Qty) % 2 = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN SUM(x.Qty) % 2 = 0 THEN 2
            ELSE -1 -- SUM(x.Qty) IS NULL
        END AS CaseSumOfQty
FROM (
    SELECT 1, 100 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 200 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 301 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 0   UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, NULL
) x(OrderID, Qty)
GROUP BY x.OrderID;
```

Output:

```
OrderID SumOfQty    CaseSumOfQty
------- ----------- ------------
1       100         2
2       501         1
3       0           0
4       NULL        -1 -- SUM(x.Qty) IS NULL
```